# how set tag of images in image view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

self.title=@"Evolution";
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

int numberOfImages = 32;
CGFloat currentX = 0.0f;

for (int i=1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {

    // create image
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // put image on correct position
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.origin.x = currentX;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag=i;
    // update currentX
    currentX +=454; //mageView.frame.size.width;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, 800);
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 15;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

in above code how set tag for each image? so that i can use that tag  to call bigger image from web services as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imageView.image.tag=i;
```

OR

```
[imageView.image setTag:i];
```

Answer (score 0):

In general we can write like this :

```
imgview.image.tag=i;
```